# is it possible to set the default OS as windows for mbp?

Tags: mac

I installed windows 10 with Boot Camp on my mbp.

each time I restart windows, my mbp switch to mac by default.

is it possible to set the default OS as windows?

windows update needs restart many times, I have to sit in front of my mbp to set startup disk manually, if there is no way to set the default OS.

Comment: What happens if you set the startup disk before reboot?

Comment: windows update needs restart many times, I have to sit in front of my mbp to set startup disk manually, if there is no way to set the default OS.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Tetsujin is referring to the macOS control panel, where you can change the default startup volume. This setting will stick! IIRC, the Boot Camp control panel on Windows also has this setting.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you so much. You've solved my problem! plz mv it to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default startup disk from System Preferences > Startup Disk.

There may be caveats depending what macOS your mac is running & how its disk is formatted.
Windows cannot read APFS disks, so if you are on High Sierra or newer, then the equivalent control panel in Windows - Boot Camp - will not be able to change this back & you'll have to hold Opt at boot up in order to get back to your Mac install; then change the control panel back to Mac once you're booted.